# How to validate the string and alphanumberic values?

Tags: javascript

Here only one scenario getting fail, thats not accepting alphanumeric values in the validate function. My other scenario are good.Please see the below code.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/8/)

```
function validateChunk(s)
{
    return !!s.match(/^[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?$/);
}

function filterValid(v)
{
    return !v;
}

function testCases(str)
{
    var chunks = str.split(",");
    var validated = chunks.map(validateChunk);
    return (0 === validated.filter(filterValid).length);

}
```

Actual output :

```
"stack1(1),flow3test(7),over1,temp5"; - false
```

Expected output :

```
"stack1(1),flow3test(7),over1,temp5"; - true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't allow digits prior to the `(`, but all of your test data has digits there. If you want to allow the digits, change it to `/^[a-z0-9]+(?:\(\d+\))?$/`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/9/)

If you want to allow digits, but not in the first position (a fairly common restriction), then `/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:\(\d+\))?$/`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/10/)